# Sending POST via curl to the server doesn't work

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I am trying to send a POST request to the server (JBOSS) which is running on `localhost:9090` as shown below but it doesn't seem to be working. I mean, I am not seeing my webservice getting executed. Am I doing everything right below?

Since  `$_POST["mydata"]` contains the following :

`[{ "name": "FirstName", "value": "Mickey" }, { "name": "LastName", "value": "Mouse" }]`

which is the result of running `JSON.stringify()` on the javascript object (using serializeArray()), I am not sending `application/json` related thing in the header.

```
$urlTest = 'http://localhost:9090/JAXRS_POST_Request/rest/Request/insertDataToDB';

        $rCURL = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
        curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST["myData"]);
        curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_URL, $urlTest);
        curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response_post = curl_exec($rCURL);
        curl_close($rCURL);
```

But if I have to manually test the webservice using a client like POSTMAN, I have to specify under headers as `Content-Type : application/json` and send it like this through the Body and it works perfectly fine there :

[image]

But while sending the request via curl, since `JSON.stringify()` converts the javascript object to string to send it to the server, I am confused whether I need to use header thing in my POST request or not.

P.S. A simple curl based `GET` request has worked fine for me so my application is successfully contacting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$urlTest = 'http://localhost:9090/JAXRS_POST_Request/rest/Request/insertDataToDB';

$data = 'FirstName=Mickey&LastName=Mouse';

$rCURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);//
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_URL, $urlTest);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($rCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if(curl_exec($rCurl) === false){

    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($rCurl);

}else{

  $response_post = curl_exec($rCURL);

}

curl_close($rCurl);
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work. Is there a way to debug since I am not returning anything in this case but inserting only into database via webservice.

Comment: If you have access to the code for the page that your are sending the post request to, please add it to your question.  We need to know if the page is expecting json or not.  Also you may need to add an extension to your insertDataToDB file in the URL.

Comment: Actually it's a Java webservice which I wrote and the way I send it data to is mentioned in the screenshot above of POSTMAN client. Not sure if Java service code would help here?

Comment: I do not have any experience with java web service. But you do need to make sure that you are sending the data in the form/method that the web service needs it to be in. Is it expecting a normal post request where the parameters are an array, or does it want a json object with the parameters in it.  Without that knowledge I can't help you.  But run the errors code I added to my answer and see if that gives you a clue.

Comment: It is expecting JSON object and not normal post. Please let me know if this answers your question. Thanks  May I know why you updated your answer?

Comment: Did you get any errors from the script I put in my answer?

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned. It didn't throw any error and nothing happened actually. So, it doesn't seem like the request even worked.